# Android cant access location in the background

Tags: android, android-location, android-background

i'm having an issue with my app
it should send current location to a server every 20-30 seconds and it used to work.
But we have just installed it on a new phone using android 8.0 and here I can read that there are some background location limitations but I can't figure out how to get by them getting some updates a bit faster. atm I'm getting 3-4 updates an hour if the display is off

So far I'm starting my background service like this

```
intentService = new Intent(getBaseContext(), BackgroundService.class);
    mLayout = findViewById(R.id.layout);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onCreate: Startet as foregroundservioce" );
        startForegroundService(intentService);
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "onCreate: started as background service" );
        startService(intentService);
    }
```

background service onStartCommand()

```
@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // Let it continue running until it is stopped.
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        appPreferences = new AppPreferences(this.getBaseContext());
        child = appPreferences.getChild();
        lockStatic = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "taxaapp:WorkInBackground123");
        lockStatic.acquire();
        sslClientService = new SSLClientService(this);
        return START_STICKY;
    }
```

my geoLocationManager

```
public class GeoLocationService {
    private Timer mTimer;
    private Alarm alarm;
    private boolean tracking;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private BackgroundService _context;
    private Child child;
    private SSLClientService sslClientService;
    private long alarmTimeToStop = 0;
    private LocalDatabaseHandler ldbh;
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    /**
     * constructor initializes
     *
     * @param context
     * @param child
     */
    public GeoLocationService(BackgroundService context, Child child) {
        _context = context;
        locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        sslClientService = _context.getSSLClient();
        ldbh = new LocalDatabaseHandler(context);
        mTimer = new Timer();
        this.child = child;
    }

    /**
     * Updates the working alarm
     *
     * @param alarm
     */
    public void setAlarm(Alarm alarm) {
        if (this.alarm.getId() == 0) {
            this.alarm = alarm;
        }
        _context.sendMessageToUI(R.integer.MSG_GPS_START);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the alarm being used at the moment
     */
    public Alarm getAlarm() {
        return alarm;
    }

    /**
     * Starts location listener
     *
     * @return true if it was able to start
     */
    public boolean start() {
        boolean bool = false;
        mTimer.schedule(new TimedTask(), 20, 30000);
        if (!isTracking()) {
            alarm = new Alarm(child.getId());
            alarmTimeToStop = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L + _context.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.GpsMaxTime);
        } else {
            if (!alarm.getAlarmCoordinates().isEmpty()) {
                alarm = new Alarm(child.getId());
                alarmTimeToStop = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L + _context.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.GpsMaxTime);
//                sslClientService.SendAlarm(new Alarm(child.getId(), alarm.getLastAlarmCoordinates().getAddress()));
            }
        }
        // Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(_context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(_context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(_context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.e("Missing permissions", "we are missing some permissions for GPS location");
            bool = false;
        }
        if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) && locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, _context.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.GeoSettingsDistance), locationListener);
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, _context.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.GeoSettingsDistance), locationListener);
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
            tracking = true;
            bool = true;
            ldbh.addLog("Starting new alarm", 200, "GeoLocationService-Start");
        }
        return bool;
    }

    /**
     * is the tracking active
     */

    /**
     * Listens for location updates
     */
    private LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        private long time = 0;


        /**
         * Called when the location has changed.
         * <p> only accepts new location if 10seconds has passed and location accuracy is less than 30
         * <p> There are no restrictions on the use of the supplied Location object.
         *
         * @param location The new location, as a Location object.
         */
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onLocationChanged: Location Accuracy and provider: " + location.getAccuracy() + " / " + location.getProvider());
            Log.i(TAG, "onLocationChanged: TIME! " + (location.getTime() - time));
            if (location.getTime() - time > _context.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.GeoSettingsTime) && location.getAccuracy() <= _context.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.GpsAccuracy)) {
                time = location.getTime();
                // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.
                List<Address> address;
                double lat = location.getLatitude();
                double lng = location.getLongitude();
//                lat = 10.27657397;  //Kan bruges til test af dårlige kordinator
//                lng = 56.21009964;  //Kan bruges til test af dårlige kordinator
                AlarmCoordinates alarmCoordinates = new AlarmCoordinates(lat, lng, alarm.getId());
                
                Log.i(TAG, "onLocationChanged: new coordinates!");
                NewAlarmCoordinates(alarmCoordinates);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're in Doze mode.  https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby  After turning off the screen, the device will shortly go into Doze, where it will only provide events to applications every 15 minutes or so (except for high priority push messages and alarms).  This is expected behavior.

The only way to turn it off is to have your users whitelist your app from battery optimizations.  It cannot be done programatically.  And don't expect many users to actually do that.  In reality, you need to code around it and live with few location updates while their screen is off.

You can also use ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS but the use of that is restricted on the play store and you need to ask for an exemption.

Comment: hmm Ill try and look into that, my app wont be on the play store, and only installed on phones I'm having access to my self so whitelisting would not be a problem